# Why don't electrons from conduction band jump to the acceptor level?

Tags: semiconductors

One basic idea of Band theory is that electrons always try to occupy the lower energy states. Acceptor levels have vacant low energy states . Then why do electrons from Conduction band don't fall back into acceptor levels? Why always valance band electrons go to acceptor levels giving holes?

Comment: Never heard of recombination?

Comment: sorry i am a total beginner in this subject...enlighten me

Comment: First go through [this wiki on carrier generation recombination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_generation_and_recombination) and get back if 
 still need enlightenment..

Comment: @SouhardyaMondal The last diagram shown [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/316835/38098) may help a little. The diagram helps differentiate between N, I, and P type semiconductor materials. Perhaps you'll see the valence and conduction bands in a way that may help provide some intuition. (Keep in mind the large-number statistical effects of thermal energy in solid state matter.)