# Charge carriers of an electric current

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, electromagnetism

I was under the impression that electric current was caused exclusively by the flow of electrons moving through the wire.

However upon doing a little more research on electric current, [it is said](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_current) that charge carriers **are often** electrons moving through a wire. What other charge carriers are there besides electrons when applied to electric circuits?

Comment: In the context of semiconductors, both electrons (negative) and holes (positive) are charge carriers. There's more detailed explanation in chapters 3 and 4 of Sedra/Smith, Microelectronic Circuits.

Comment: Some of what I write [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/316835/38098) may help a little. Pay particular attention to the band structure diagram there (which comes from this Wiki [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_band_structure).) It helps a little to understand some ideas related to *thermalization* and *kT equipartition*.

Comment: Also of note in a circuit: positive ions carry charges between the anode and cathode of a battery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the reference from your question states, "An electric current is the rate of flow of electric charge past a point or region". The rate of flow **IS** an electric current, not that the flow **CAUSES** electric current, according to the Wikipedia article.

Both electromagnetic and non-electromagnetic forces can **CAUSE** the movement of charge carriers. In the context of semiconductor devices, there are [two kinds of current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_current) regarding "flow of electric charge". The drift current is caused by an electric field; the diffusion current is a current caused by the diffusion of charge carriers. Both kinds of current can include movement of positive (**holes**) and/or negative (**electrons**) charge carriers. This statement answers your question "in the context of semiconductor devices".

ADDENDUM:
Be careful when learning and using terminology, in particular, in electronic engineering. As with language in general, EE terminology is a result of historical process; its use and understanding can include intricate details.

For example, Ampère's circuital law, one of Maxwell equations, includes a term named "[displacement current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current)", which is not associated with any movement of charges.

Make sure your understand these intricacies and know the electromagnetic theory and you will not be baffled by seeming paradoxes, as, for example, the fact that the signal velocity in wires is higher than the speed of charge carrier transport.

Answer (score 2):

In free space or in liquids or gases, ions can also be charge carriers.

Batteries often involve ions moving in a liquid (or gel) electrolyte, releasing or combining with electrons at the electrodes.

Gas discharge tubes, and lightning flashes, and plasma, involve ions carrying charge (they may involve positive ions moving in one direction concurrent with free electrons moving in the other).